# Kubernetes node behind the NAT

Tags: kubernetes, nat, flannel

```
 Network1               Network2
(MASER, NODE1) <=NAT=> (NODE2, NODE3)
```

Is it possible to make overlay network work on nodes behind the NAT (without real IP addresses)? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this might not be good idea, as Kubernetes needs a stable networking between master(s) and nodes or you might get into multiple problems. Not sure if this will work in your case but you could look at [federation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/federation-v2) between clusters.

Also I'm pretty sure here is the answer:

> Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any
>   networking implementation (barring any intentional network
>   segmentation policies):
>
> - all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
> - **all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without
>     NAT**
> - the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others
>     see it as